# How to fix Operator button bugs of my calculator app in android studio?

Tags: java, android, calculator

When click operator buttons( +, -, *, / ) in calculator app made by android studio, before putting number buttons, the calculator is closed, which means putting number and then putting operator is okay. I want nothing happens when click operator, before number clicked.

- case 1 :   number buttons click -> operator button click     is working.
- case 2 :   operator button click or equals button click      is closed.

Comment: Set the operator button to disabled with `button.setEnabled(false)`. When a user presses one of the number buttons in the `OnPressed` function enable them. If the user presses a "clear" button or something equivalent then disable your operator buttons again because the field implicitly has no numbers.

Comment: Thank you amza! It works :)